# simple toric variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

simple question.
I am looking at a presentation of the ring $k[x,yx^{-1}]$ in the following form $k[a,b]/I$ where $I$ is an ideal.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $x$ and $y/x$ are algebrically independent since the field of fraction of $k[x.y/x]$ is $k(x.y)$. If there is map from $k[a,b]$ to $k[x,y/x]$ sending $a$ to $x$ and $b$ to $y/x$ then the kernel $I$ is definitely a prime ideal as $k[x.y/x]$ is a domain. Now equating transcendence degree of $k[a.b]/I$ and $k[x.y/x]$ over $k$ we can conclude that the kernel is zero.

Comment: That «$x$ and $y/x$ agebraically independent» *means* the map from $k[a,b]\to k[x,y/z]$ is injective. There is no need to invoke further technology! Of course, one has to prove at some point that $x$ and $y/x$ agebraically independent...

Comment: @Mariano Suarez Alvarez don't the alg. independence of $x$ and $\frac{y}{x}$ is an immediate consequence of the independence of $x,y$???